# Given: $f(x)=x^2-2x+5$ Find both the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum on the interval $[0,4]$

Tags: calculus

I know the coordinates for the absolute maximum are $(4,13)$ and the coordinates for the absolute minimum are $(1,4)$

Am I done here or is there more work to be done for this problem? Seems too simple.

Is the answer only the $x$-coordinate or both coordinates?

Comment: 13 is the absolute maximum and 4 is the absolute minimum. But some might refer to the points. If the latter is the case, then your answer is right.

Comment: why would 1 not be the absolute minimum?

Comment: Because the function doesn't attain the value $1$ for any $x$ in the given interval.

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly what they ask you

"Find both the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum on the interval $[0,4]$"

then you should give only the $y$-coordinates as answers ($13$ and $4$).

If they ask you also

"For what values of $x$ does the function reach that maximum/minimum?"

then you should give also the $x$ values $4$ and $1$ as answers.